# How can I calculate two circles intersection in two points?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

[image]

Where the equation of two circle:
${X_a}^2 + (y_a - p)^2 = {r_a}^2$

${X_b}^2 + (y_b - p)^2 = {r_b}^2$

I want to know how to get $(X_c, Y_c)$.

Comment: Well, notice that $(X_c,Y_c)$ has to satisfy the equation of the first, as well as the second, circle, because $(X_c,Y_c)$ belongs to both (it is their intersection). Unless you have any aditional conditions, you should find two possible solutions, one for each intersection point as shown in the diagram.

Comment: Your equations for the circles are not correct.  For the first it is $(x-X_a)^2+(y-Y_a)^2=r_a^2$  Also note that you seem to assume $Y_a$ and $y_a$ are the same.  Usually they are different but related if one is capital and one lower case.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the two equations, set them both equal to zero. 
 $$X_a^2+(y_a−p)^2-r_a^2=0$$
$$X_b^2+(y_b−p)^2-r_b^2=0$$
Then subtract them from one another you will get a linear equation which passes through both intersection points.
You can then set that equal to one of the circle equations to get a quadratic for the intersections.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a system of equations.
$$\begin{cases}
(x-h_1)^2+(y-k_1)^2=r_1^2\\
(x-h_2)^2+(y-k_2)^2=r_2^2
\end{cases}$$
If you expand it out and subtract them from each other, you can get a linear equation. You can then solve that linear equation for one variable and substitute it into either of the equations, and you end up with a quadratic that you can solve with the quadratic method.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Let $(0,0)$ be the center of the first circle.
So we need to solve system of two equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+y^2=r_1^2 \\ 
(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2 = r_2^2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Subtract the second equation from the first:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+y^2=r_1^2 \\ 
-2x_2x - 2y_2y + (x_2^2+y_2^2+r_1^2-r_2^2) = 0\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Thus, we need to calculate intersection of the first circle and the line $Ax+By+C=0$ where $A = -2x_2, B = -2y_2 , C = x_2^2+y_2^2+r_1^2-r_2^2$